# Bootstrap radio buttons - adding variables with jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I built a form using Bootstrap. The user clicks a radio button and a number is displayed at the bottom of the page.

```
   <!-- FOOTER -->
   <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-offset-3 col-xs-12 col-lg-6">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="row text-center">
          <div class="text-center col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <h2>Broadband Speed Calculator</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="text-center col-lg-12"> 
            <!-- CONTACT FORM https://github.com/jonmbake/bootstrap3-contact-form -->
                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="" id="broadbandForm">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="video" class="col-xs-12 control-label text-left">Number of people who use streaming video (eg. Youtube or Netflix) on your network</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                            <label class="btn btn-primary active"><input class="BroadbandRadioClass" type="radio" name="videoStream" value="0" checked>0</label>
                            <label class="btn btn-primary"><input class="BroadbandRadioClass" type="radio" name="videoStream" value="9">1</label>
                            <label class="btn btn-primary"><input class="BroadbandRadioClass" type="radio" name="videoStream" value="18">2</label>
                            <label class="btn btn-primary"><input class="BroadbandRadioClass" type="radio" name="videoStream" value="27">3</label>
                            <label class="btn btn-primary"><input class="BroadbandRadioClass" type="radio" name="videoStream" value="36">4+</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>                

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="videoChat" class="col-xs-12 control-label text-left">Number of people who use video chat (eg. Skype or Facetime) on your network</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                            <label class="btn btn-primary active"><input class="BroadbandRadioClass" type="radio" name="videoChat" value="0" checked>0</label>
                            <label class="btn btn-primary"><input class="BroadbandRadioClass" type="radio" name="videoChat" value="9">1</label>
                            <label class="btn btn-primary"><input class="BroadbandRadioClass" type="radio" name="videoChat" value="18">2</label>
                            <label class="btn btn-primary"><input class="BroadbandRadioClass" type="radio" name="videoChat" value="27">3</label>
                            <label class="btn btn-primary"><input class="BroadbandRadioClass" type="radio" name="videoChat" value="36">4+</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="gaming" class="col-xs-12 control-label text-left">Number of people who use online gaming on your network</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                            <label class="btn btn-primary active"><input class="BroadbandRadioClass" type="radio" name="gaming" value="0" checked>0</label>
                            <label class="btn btn-primary"><input class="BroadbandRadioClass" type="radio" name="gaming" value="5">1</label>
                            <label class="btn btn-primary"><input class="BroadbandRadioClass" type="radio" name="gaming" value="10">2</label>
                            <label class="btn btn-primary"><input class="BroadbandRadioClass" type="radio" name="gaming" value="15">3</label>
                            <label class="btn btn-primary"><input class="BroadbandRadioClass" type="radio" name="gaming" value="20">4+</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>                       

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="audioStream" class="col-xs-12 control-label text-left">Number of people who use streaming audio on your network</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                            <label class="btn btn-primary active"><input class="BroadbandRadioClass" type="radio" name="audioStream" value="0" checked>0</label>
                            <label class="btn btn-primary"><input class="BroadbandRadioClass" type="radio" name="audioStream" value=".32">1</label>
                            <label class="btn btn-primary"><input class="BroadbandRadioClass" type="radio" name="audioStream" value=".64">2</label>
                            <label class="btn btn-primary"><input class="BroadbandRadioClass" type="radio" name="audioStream" value=".96">3</label>
                            <label class="btn btn-primary"><input class="BroadbandRadioClass" type="radio" name="audioStream" value="1.28">4+</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>    

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="generalUse" class="col-xs-12 control-label text-left">Number of people who use the Internet for general use (shopping, banking, e-mail, social media, etc.) on your network</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                            <label class="btn btn-primary active"><input class="BroadbandRadioClass" type="radio" name="generalUse" value="0" checked>0</label>
                            <label class="btn btn-primary"><input class="BroadbandRadioClass" type="radio" name="generalUse" value=".5">1</label>
                            <label class="btn btn-primary"><input class="BroadbandRadioClass" type="radio" name="generalUse" value="1">2</label>
                            <label class="btn btn-primary"><input class="BroadbandRadioClass" type="radio" name="generalUse" value="1.5">3</label>
                            <label class="btn btn-primary"><input class="BroadbandRadioClass" type="radio" name="generalUse" value="2">4+</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div id="CalculationResult" class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-4">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            <!-- END CONTACT FORM -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- / FOOTER -->
```

I used the following code first, which works fine, except when the Bootstrap script is included. Then it breaks. I understand that this is because of the way Bootstrap handles the form.

```
$("input[type=radio]").click(function() {
var Broadbandtotal = 0;
$("input[type=radio]:checked").each(function() {
    Broadbandtotal += parseFloat($(this).val());
});

$( "#CalculationResult" ).html( "You need at least " + Broadbandtotal );
console.log(Broadbandtotal);
});
```

This is fine, except I want to use Bootstrap. So I replaced a few things and ended up with this:

```
$(".btn").click(function() {
var Broadbandtotal = 0;
$(" .active input:radio").each(function() {
    Broadbandtotal += parseFloat($(this).val());
});
$( "#CalculationResult" ).html( "You need at least " + Broadbandtotal ); 
console.log(Broadbandtotal);    
});
```

This actually works, but has a very strange quirk. You have to click 2 buttons for the number to be displayed at the bottom (i.e. click button 1, it tells you the answer is "0" - click button 2 and it tells you the answer is "1" which is actually what you should get by clicking the first button.)

Am I missing something here? It seems like it should run the same as the first code, which has no issues. It seems like it is somehow adding the variables up after the rest of the code has run, but I haven't been able to figure this out. The console also says the same thing. Hints needed desperately! Thanks...

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/99x50s2s/234/

Comment: Can you include the html to make this question more complete?

Comment: @Richard I updated it thanks

Comment: Seems like the first buttons are selected by default. Am I right?

Comment: Are you sure that the `.active` class is being applied before the click event gets processed?  I am suspecting that it gets applied after.

Comment: @stephen.vakil this seems correct. I'm still at a loss for how to fix it though. I've tried a bunch of different things here

Comment: @VimalanJayaGanesh They are selected by default, yes. I'm going to try deselecting everything by default and see if that fixes it. Edit: didn't fix it.

Comment: Will `mouseup` instead of `click` solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made both your click events into one change event:

```
$("input[type=radio]").on('change',function() {
    var Broadbandtotal = 0;
    $("input[type=radio]:checked").each(function() {
        Broadbandtotal += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });

    $( "#CalculationResult" ).html( "You need at least " + Broadbandtotal );
    console.log(Broadbandtotal);

    $(" .active input:radio").each(function() {
        Broadbandtotal += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });

});
```

Comment: This is it! Thanks to all replies.